# How to get every possible combination to choose k object from a set of n elements

Tags: combinatorics

How can I get the actual combinations to choose k objects of n elements.

The binomial coefficient only tells me how many possiblities exist, but I actually don't know the combinations. What methods are there?

Comment: Example for $n=5,k=2$ is $(x,x,0,0,0),(x,0,x,0,0),(x,0,0,x,0),(x,0,0,0,x),(0,x,x,0,0),\dots$ et cetera. Exactly $\binom52=10$ in total. Speaks for itself I would say. Does that answer your question?

Comment: @drhab I need to know the combinations, not the number of combinations. So, I rather need a clear method then a formula I guess.

Comment: I just gave you the combinations. Things like $(x,0,x,0,0)$. If that is not satisfactory then what exactly *is* a combination in this context?

Comment: You gave me an example. I am aware of that. The thing is, that one can easily generate this sequences by hand, when the set isn't too big, but whats the method. Your method seems to generate duplicates. Unlike the binomial coefficient which sumarizes duplicates, or am I wrong?

Comment: There are many such algorithms in the computer science literature, for example Algorithm L in section 7.2.1.3 of *The Art of Computer Programming: Volume 4A, Combinatorial Algorithms, Part 1* by Donald E. Knuth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Brute force method: to obtain all possible subsets represent every number from $0$ to $2^n-1$ in binary form and pick out from the set the elements which binary position is filled with $1$. If you are interested only in subsets with $k$ elements, check if the sum of binary digits is equal to $k$.

An algorithm which does not require generation of wrong-sized subsets is the following.

1. Set $k$ counters with indices $1,2,\dots k$ to the lowest possible values (from $1$ to $k$).
2. Increment the admissible counter. The counter with index $\ell$ is admissible if its current value $m_\ell$ is less than its largest possible value ($n-k+\ell$) and all counters with higher indices have the largest possible values (from $n-k+\ell+1$ to $n$).
3. If the value $m_\ell$ of the incremented counter is not the largest possible ($n-k+\ell$), reset the indices of all counters with higher indices to the values from $m_\ell+1$ to $m_\ell+k-l$.
4. goto 2.

An example of this algorithm can be found in a comment for $n=5$, $k=2$.

More effective algorithms are much more complicated. See for example https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/1.9781611973068.107

Comment: Sounds like a good idea. But is there a mathematical way to obtain binary numbers with only 3 positions set to 1? I guess this would be a more cleaner way rather than iterate through all binary numbers and check the sum.

Comment: I have edited the answer. Is it what you are looking for?